# How to Use A CardLayout in My Situation

Tags: java, swing, pong

I have not been able to find a way to use a CardLayout that works.

I am creating a Pong game. I have a class that extends a JFrame and two classes that extend a JPanel. I am trying to make it so that when the method gets fired in the the first JPanel, it switches from the first JPanel to the second JPanel.

How would I do this, and please provide code.

Comment: Please provide code? Why not you first? How else are we to know what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Check the comment in the answer

Comment: But next time, show code, don't ask for code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is use a `CardLayout` on the parent component that will hold your two `JPanel`s. When you add the `JPanel`s to the parent component, you'll need to provide a `String` for each one, which will be used later to switch between the cards.

```
CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
JPanel parentComponent = new JPanel(cardLayout);
parentComponent.add( jPanel1, "Panel 1" );
parentComponent.add( jPanel2, "Panel 2" );
```

Then when you want to switch the cards, you need to call a method on the `CardLayout` layout manager, so you'll need to get it from the parent component and cast it, or just save a reference to it when you create your parent component. Now to switch the cards:

```
cardLayout.show( parentComponent, "Panel 1" ); // Shows panel 1
cardLayout.show( parentComponent, "Panel 2" ); // Shows panel 2
```

- [How to Use CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: It's loading it (because I can hear the sounds from the first panel), but it's just showing an empty frame. Here is my source: http://pastebin.com/2L4amutZ

Comment: @Cg2916: You're not adding the parent component to the `JFrame` at all.

Comment: @Cg2916: How'd you add the `JPanel`s to the parent `JPanel`?

Comment: I'm still new at this obviously.